# Store pointer address in malloced memory

Tags: c, pointers

This feels like a silly question, but I just can't work out a clean solution and can't find a similar question in the mass of other pointer related questions.

I have some dynamically allocated memory of unknown type and want to store a pointer inside it at the start. Dynamic memory returned by malloc should be suitably aligned so I don't think I have to worry about alignment when writing to the start of the allocated block.

This is my code, which works, but I'm representing a pointer as a 64-bit integer and want to do it in a more clean/portable way:

```
void *my_area = malloc(512);
void *my_pointer = get_my_pointer();
((long long *) my_area)[0] = (long long) my_pointer;
```

Comment: Or you can use `uintptr_t` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast to `long long` is just extra baggage.  Cast to `void *` instead.

```
void *my_area = malloc(512);
void *my_pointer = get_my_pointer();
((void **) my_area)[0] = my_pointer;
```

(I assume that this is for some kind of freelist or the like, i.e., you don't need to use the structure at the same time.)

Answer (score 1):

What will be found in `my_area[0]` is pointer to something, right ?

Then you can allocate my_area to be of type `void **`, which represent a pointer to a pointer containing memory area.

```
void **my_area = malloc(512 * sizeof(*my_area)); // alloc 512 pointer sized memory blocks
void *my_pointer = get_my_pointer();
my_area[0] = my_pointer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a struct with internal array of 8 bytes. Replace all the long long type references with your custom struct. This way you will not depend on platform-specific size of long long. The struct will be 64 bits on all platforms(you can add #pragma pack if you worry about alignment )

Comment: `long long` is already guaranteed to be at least 64 bits on all platforms, using a `struct` instead is not going to improve anything.

Comment: That's true only for C99 and C++11. Besides, being larger than 64bit breaks the portability with the same success.