# Copy memory address to a memory block

Tags: c, pointers, memcpy

I haven't been programming in C for a very long time I and have recently decided to come back to it. I'm posting this question because there's something I can't fully understand about the `memcpy` function. I'd like to be able to copy memory addresses into a block of memory. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Person {
    char name[255];
    char last_name[255];
    short age;
};

int main(void) {
    struct Person* person = calloc(1, sizeof(struct Person));

    strcpy(person->name, "John");
    strcpy(person->last_name, "Travolta");
    person->age = 66;

    void* buffer = calloc(1, sizeof(struct Person*));

    // This won't copy the address of `person` into buffer.
    // I don't understand why.
    memcpy(buffer, &person, sizeof(struct Person*));

    // If I want to allocate and copy the contents where `person`
    // is pointing to that works absolutely fine:
    //
    //     void* buffer = calloc(1, sizeof(struct Person));
    //     memcpy(buffer, person, sizeof(struct Person));
    //
    // But that's not what I want. I don't want a copy of the data.
    // I want a copy of `person`, NOT a copy of the data where `person`
    // is pointing to.

    struct Person* ptr = (struct Person*) buffer;

    printf("person address: %p\tptr address: %p.\n", person, ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

I've compiled it with: `gcc -Wall test-ptr.c -o test-ptr`. When I run it I'm expecting the `printf` to give me exactly the same addresses. However this is what I'm getting:

`person address: 0x800a40000    ptr address: 0x800644008.`

Now some background for the above question. Why would I like to copy a memory address into a memory block? Just for learning purposes I'm implementing a dynamic array data structure completely from scratch. Its interface is:

```
struct DynamicArray new_dynamic_array(size_t element_size);
void* da_get_nth(struct DynamicArray* da, size_t i);
void da_append(struct DynamicArray* da, void* element);
void da_insert(struct DynamicArray* da, void* element, size_t i);
void* da_delete(struct DynamicArray* da, size_t i);
```

If I request a memory block (using either `calloc` or `malloc`) and then fill it in with data I'd like to store in the dynamic array the addresses of those memory blocks instead of making the dynamic array to hold a copy of such data.

To sum it up: the dynamic array operations that I've defined are implemented using `memcpy` and currently is not having the desired effect (copying data works as expected though). I'd like to effectively be able to hold in my dynamic array *any* arbitrary data type (either a copy of the data or a copy of a memory address, depending of course of how the dynamic array operations are called: if I pass a pointer data is copied but if I pass the address of a pointer its memory address should be copied instead).

I've found the following answer: [Store pointer address in malloced memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274583/store-pointer-address-in-malloced-memory) which seems to be the answer for this issue. However I don't fully understand it and also this would imply that my dynamic array implementation would need to distinguish when to use `memcpy` or when to directly assign a value. Can this problem be solved using probably another function than `memcpy`? Or is something else that I'm fully missing or not understanding? What is wrong about my reasoning in the example?

Sorry for the length of the post and thanks in advance!

Comment: What about: `void *buffer = &person;` instead of the `malloc/memcpy`. This is [probably] what you want. Or, based on _most_ of the code you have, instead of that, do: `struct Person** ptr = buffer; printf("person address: %p\tptr address: %p.\n", person, *ptr);` (Note the double star pointer).

Comment: I believe you must change the line `struct Person* ptr = (struct Person*) buffer;` to `struct Person* ptr = *(struct Person**) buffer;` This is because `buffer` points to a pointer which points to a `struct Person`.

Comment: "This won't copy the address of `person` into buffer." -- The variable `person` has the type `struct Person *`. The address of `person` (which is `&person`) therefore has the type `struct Person **`. Do you really want to copy such a double pointer into `buffer`, which would make `buffer` a triple pointer?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Why double or triple pointers are involved here? The way I interpret `memcpy(buffer, &person, sizeof(struct Person*));` is: Copy `sizeof(struct Person*)` bytes (in my machine this gives me 8 bytes) starting from `&person` into `buffer`. So I'm telling to effectively copy the 8 bytes that `person` is supposed to hold. I can't see why copying a number (a pointer is just a number, right?) into a memory block is not straightforward.

Comment: @N001: Your interpretation stated in your last comment is correct. However, your comment in your code `This won't copy the address of person into buffer. I don't understand why.` seems to be misleading, because you are not copying/not attempting to copy the **address of** `person` into `buffer`, but rather the **value of** `person`. When you refer to the address of a pointer, this normally means the pointer's own location in memory, not the value it holds (which also is an address).

Comment: @N001: If you follow the advice I gave in my first comment, does your program then work as intended? Both printed pointer values are the same, then.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yes, that's working correctly! So `memcpy` is effectively storing the pointer address in my example. The issue was when I was retrieving it, correct? As you mentioned the key here seems to be: `struct Person* ptr = *(struct Person**) buffer;` and the `memcpy` call in the example is correct, right?

Comment: @N001: I believe your use of the terminology is wrong/misleading or at least ambiguous. When you say in your previous comment `is effectively storing the pointer address`, are you referring to the **address of** the pointer, i.e. the result of applying `&` to the pointer? Or do you mean the **value of** the pointer (which also is an address)? This is a very important distinction.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I mean the following: `buffer` is containing 8 bytes with the memory address of person (`&person`) hence `struct Person* ptr = *(struct Person**) buffer;` works.

Comment: @N001: "The issue was when I was retrieving it, correct?" -- Well, the issue was that you weren't retrieving it at all. You were just printing the address of the pointer that you copied into the memory buffer `buffer`, without ever reading it. The replacement code now dereferences that address, so it actually reads the value of the pointer that is stored in that memory buffer.

Comment: @N001: Just for clarification: Even if `buffer` is officially of type `void*`, you are using it as a `struct Person**`. That's why you must cast it do that data type, before dereferencing it. After dereferencing it, you get the value of the pointer that you copied into the memory buffer `buffer`. The data type of that value is `struct Person *`.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("person address: %p\tptr address: %p.\n", person, ptr);
```

Here, `ptr` is the same pointer as `buffer`. It is the pointer to the pointer, not the pointer which is stored in `buffer`.

It comes from this declaration:

```
struct Person* ptr = (struct Person*) buffer;
```

where it is very plain that `ptr` is the same pointer as `buffer`, except that the types are different.

What you want is:

```
// The cast is not required in C, but I'm keeping it
struct Person **pptr = (struct Person **) buffer;
```

Now `pptr` is a pointer to a pointer to `Person`, which is exactly what we want.

We can evaluate `*pptr`:

```
 printf("person address: %p\tpptr address: %p.\n", (void *) person, (void *) *pptr);
```

Note that the casts are needed for strict ISO C conformance; the `%p` conversion specifier requires an argument of type `void *`, not just any pointer.

We don't need the `memcpy` if we just work with `pptr`; we can store the value using:

```
*pptr = person;  // instead of memcpy(&pptr, &person, sizeof pptr);
```